# Prove $\mathcal{H}$ is a hilbert space. Where $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ be two Hilbert spaces where $H=H_1+H_2$

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ be two Hilbert spaces. We define the space $\mathcal{H}$ by 
$$\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_1 \oplus \mathcal{H}_2= \{  x=(x_1,x_2) : x_1 \in \mathcal{H}_1
                                                            ,x_2 \in \mathcal{H}_2 \} $$
and
$$\forall x,y \in \mathcal{H}, x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2), <x,y>_{\mathcal{H}} = <x_1,y_1>_{\mathcal{H}_1} 
                         +<x_2,y_2>\mathcal{H}_2  $$
Prove that $\mathcal{H}$ is a hilbert space

---

Need to show that it is a 1) an inner product space rules are obeyed and 2) that it is complete.  Having issues with showing that it s complete. So if it  is cauchy it converges in the space. Having trouble to notate that it is cauchy with $<.,.>$

**should used diff notation that $\oplus$**

---

Attempt 1

Suppose that $(X_n,Y_n) \in H$ are Cauchy so $X_n=(x_{n1},x_{n2})$ and $Y_n=(y_{n1},y_{n2})$. So 
      $$<X_n,Y_n>_\mathcal{H}=<x_{n1},y_{n1}>_{\mathcal{H_1}}+ <x_{n2},y_{n2}>_{\mathcal{H_2}} $$
So  each  $<x_{n1},y_{n1}>_{\mathcal{H_1}}$ are cauchy then they converge to some $<x_1,y_1>_\mathcal{H_1}$ and $<x_2,y_2>_\mathcal{H_1}$ that is $<X,Y> \in \mathcal{H}$

**I am not sure about my notation with Cauchy. I dont feel confortable with the def of cauchy in Inner product spaces that is my real question**

Comment: Show that if  $(x_n,y_n) \in H$ is a cauchy sequence, then so are $x_n \in H_1$ and $y_n \in H_2$. Then they converge to some $x$ and $y$ by the completeness of $H_1,H_2$, so by definition $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm of $\mathcal{H}_1 \oplus \mathcal{H}_2$ is the sum of the norms of the components.

So if $(x_n,y_n)\in \mathcal{H}_1 \oplus \mathcal{H}_2$ is a Cauchy sequence, both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are Cauchy in their spaces, so they are convergent. From where it follows that $(x_n,y_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: well, i see that you already got the same hint in the comments a few seconds ago...

Comment: $x_n,y_n$ are two dim. something like $x_n=(x_{n1},x_{n2})$